# How to return from async function on error

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, async-await

```
 await conn.getconnection().catch((error)=>{
        console.log("No connection");
        return;
    });
    let collection = conn.getdb().collection(type);
```

```
async function getconnection(){
    client = new MongoClient(url);
    await client.connect();
    db = client.db(dbName);
    console.log("Connected to db");
}
```

The above code is used for connecting the mongodb database. But on not connecting to the database the async function is not going back and the collection is trying to execute causing error. How do i stop execution of function and return to parent function?

---

Note:-The function works properly when database is running. But when not running the app crashes. I want the error to be caught and not crash.

Error is

```
No connection
let collection = conn.getdb().collection(type);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
```

Edit:-

```
await conn.getconnection().catch(console.error);
    let collection = conn.getdb().collection(type);
    console.log("Entered collection");
    await collection.updateOne(query,{$set : newdata})
        .then(()=>{
            res.send("Done");
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            res.send("Error");
        })
    conn.closedb();
```

The issue with adding catch altogether is the connection does not get closed if connection is error happens after connection is successfull. So an error happens when the function is called again.

But I can't close connection using finally because if error happens in `connect()` function then no connection is there to close. So error happens in finally

Comment: Remove the `.catch()` entirely and then catch errors on the caller of this function with `.catch()`.  `return` from this `.catch()` just eats the error so the `await` thinks everything was successful.  You need the `await` to get the error so it will throw and immediately error out of the `async` function.  The caller of this `async` function then needs to catch and handle that error.

Comment: More code context would be required to make a complete recommendation on how to fix this code as we can't see the call tree, can't see where you're storing things and thus don't really know how to properly handle such an error in your code structure.  The one thing that is clear is that you shouldn't be "eating" the error the way you are.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the  issue and full code. Kindly do check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this code is a bit messy because you're coding by "side effect".  You call something like `getConnection()` and it apparently has a side effect that it sets a couple of variables in some higher scope (`client` and `db`). These are not instance variables of an object.  They aren't returned from the function so that caller can use them.  They are stuffed into some higher scoped variable.  This means that if a second incoming requests calls `getconnection()` before the first caller has finished using it, then you will overwrite those higher level variables and probably the first values won't get closed or released like they should.  This is a separate problem that must be fixed.

Again, as you only show a tiny a context of code here, we can't really make larger recommendations on how best to fix this.  Probably you should make something like `getConnection()` just return the connection and not stuff it anywhere and then let the caller use the value they got and release/close it themselves.  Then, multiple callers can call `getConnection()` and nobody will tromp on the other's value.  But, there are other designs too where connections are cached/shared or forced to be serialized.  **You need to fix this also as you likely have concurrency issues the way it is.**

Anyway, back to the main question you were asking.  Your function for getting the connection here:

```
async function getconnection(){
    client = new MongoClient(url);
    await client.connect();
    db = client.db(dbName);
    console.log("Connected to db");
}
```

will reject if `client.connect()` fails.  So, the caller of this function needs to properly handle that rejection.  The only place you show calling that function is here where you're logging the error, but allowing execution of your code to continue.  You need to properly "handle" that error.

```
await conn.getconnection().catch(console.error);
    let collection = conn.getdb().collection(type);
    console.log("Entered collection");
    await collection.updateOne(query,{$set : newdata})
        .then(()=>{
            res.send("Done");
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
            res.send("Error");
        })
    conn.closedb();
```

I would suggest rewriting that like this:

```
try {
    await conn.getconnection();
} catch(e) {
    console.error('error getting database connection', e);
    res.status(500).send('Error connecting to database');
    return;
}
try {
    const collection = conn.getdb().collection(type);
    // may need to sanitize the query variable to make sure it's safe
    await collection.updateOne(query, { $set: newdata });
    res.send("Done");
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send("Database error");
} finally {
    conn.closedb();
}
```

This accomplishes the following things:

1. It handles a rejection from `conn.getconnection()` directly and separately as you don't want to execute any more code after that error other than sending an error response.
2. It does not mix `await` and `.then()` and `.catch()`.  Pick one style of the other for any given function as flow control gets messy and confusing when you mix them.
3. It sends an appropriate response to the request in all possible error cases.
4. It makes sure to call `conn.closedb()` in all possible error paths where the database connection was retrieved.

NOTE: You don't show where the `query` variable is coming from, but as it is being fed directly to your `.updateOne()` method, you MUST make sure it is safe.  If it is coming directly out of a form post or query string, then you probably need to sanitize it to make sure it's safe so no possible input can do unintended things to your database.

---

Flow control with multiple asynchronous operations that wish to have different error handling for different operations is more complicated with `.then().catch()` than with `async/await`, but here's one idea how you could do it:

```
function runIt() {
    return conn.getconnection().catch(e => {
        console.error('error getting database connection', e);
        res.status(500).send('Error connecting to database');
        e.statusSent = true;
        // rethrow the error to skip the following .then() handlers
        throw e;
    }).then(() => {
        const collection = conn.getdb().collection(type);
        // may need to sanitize the query variable to make sure it's safe
        return collection.updateOne(query, { $set: newdata });
    }).then(() => {
        res.send("Done");
    }).catch(e => {
        if (!e.statusSent) {
            console.error(e);
            res.status(500).send("Database error");
        }
        // make sure caller sees the rejection
        throw e;
    }).finally(() => {
        // cleanup database connection
        conn.closedb();
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh ok. I see the issues. I knew about the try-catch but I am new to .then and .catch. Didn't realize I was using then improperly. How can we write the try-catch with then catch?

Comment: I do see the issues with not returning client. I agree returning client seems to be better.

Comment: @JustaNobody - I don't know what "How can we write the try-catch with then catch?" means?  Do you mean to replace `await` and `try/catch` with `.then()` and `.catch()`?

Comment: Yeah that was what I meant. How to stop execution midway (in this case database connection before collection) if there is error using `then catch`. Since there is a function inside catch, I believe `return` just exits the function inside catch. How to overcome this? Or am I interpretting it wrong?

Comment: @JustaNobody - I wouldn't recommend using `.then()` and `.catch()` here as flow control is more complicated, but I added an example of how to do it to the end of my answer.

Comment: K thanks for the help bud